# Create sqlLit database using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi new to jQuery   i have done R&D on Different Fields but now i tried to Create sqlLit Database using JQuery  i have done Google i found this code

When i insert UserName and Mail ID and Then Enter Save button but data will Disrepair

My problem is Where data will be Stored  and then Remaining fields (Rest,Update,Drop) are not Working

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>     
    <html>     
    <head>     
    <title>Exercise 3</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>  
     html, body, h1, form, fieldset, legend, ol, li {     
        margin: 0;     
        padding: 0;     
    }     
    body{     
        background: #ffffff;     
        color: #111111;     
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;     
        padding : 20px;     
    }     
    form#mycontact{
       background: #9cbc2c;     
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;     
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;     
        padding: 20px;     
        width: 400px;     
        height: 150px;     
    }     
    form#mycontact fieldset{     
        border: none;     
        margin-bottom: 10px;     
    }     
    form#mycontact fieldset:last-of-type{     
        margin-bottom: 0;     
    }     
    form#mycontact legend{     
        color: #384313;     
        font-size: 16px;     
        font-weight: bold;     
        padding-bottom: 10px;     
    }     
    form#mycontact > fieldset > legend:before{     
        content: "Step " counter(fieldsets) ": ";     
        counter-increment: fieldsets;     
    }     
    form#mycontact fieldset fieldset legend{     
        color: #111111;     
        font-size: 13px;     
        font-weight: normal;     
        padding-bottom: 0;     
    }     
    form#mycontact ol li{     
        background: #b9cf6a;     
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);     
        border-color: #e3ebc3;     
        border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);     
        border-style: solid;     
        border-width: 2px;     
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;     
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;     
        line-height: 30px;     
        list-style: none;     
        padding: 5px 10px;     
        margin-bottom: 2px;     
    }     
    form#mycontact ol ol li {     
        background: none;     
        border: none;     
        float: left;     
    }
    form#mycontact label{     
        float: left;     
        font-size: 13px;     
        width: 110px;     
    }     
    form#mycontact fieldset fieldset label{     
        background:none no-repeat left 50%;     
        line-height: 20px;     
        padding: 0 0 0 30px;     
        width: auto;     
    }     
    form#mycontact fieldset fieldset label:hover{     
        cursor: pointer;     
    }     
    form#mycontact textarea{     
        background: #ffffff;     
        border: none;     
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;     
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;     
        -khtml-border-radius: 3px;     
        font: italic 13px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;     
        outline: none;     
        padding: 5px;     
        width: 200px;     
    }     
    form#mycontact input:not([type=submit]):focus,     
    form#mycontact textarea:focus{     
        background: #eaeaea;     
    }     
    form#mycontact button {     
        background: #384313;     
        border: none;     
        float:left;     
        -moz-border-radius: 20px;     
        -webkit-border-radius: 20px;     
        -khtml-border-radius: 20px;     
        border-radius: 20px;     
        color: #ffffff;     
        display: block;     
        font: 14px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;     
        letter-spacing: 1px;     
        margin: 7px 0 0 5px;     
        padding: 7px 20px;     
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000000;     
        text-transform: uppercase;     
    }     
    form#mycontact button:hover{     
        background: #1e2506;     
        cursor: pointer;     
    }    
    </style>
    <body>     
    <h1>CONTACT FORM</h1>     
                  <form id="mycontact">     
                    <fieldset>     
                      <legend>Your details</legend>     
                        <ol>     
                          <li>     
                            <label for="username">Name</label>     
                            <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="First and last name" >     
                            <input type="hidden" id="id"/>     
                           </li>
                           <li>
                           <label for="useremail">Email</label>     
                           <input id="useremail" type="text" placeholder="example@domain.com" >     
                           </li>
                         </ol>     
                         </fieldset>

                    <button id="btnReset" type=submit>Reset</button>     
                    <button id="submitButton" type="submit">SAVE</button>     
                    <button id="btnUpdate" type=submit>UPDATE</button>     
                    <button id="btnDrop" type=submit>DROP</button>     
                  </form><br />     
            <div id="results"></div>

    </body>

     <script type="text/javascript" >
    var createStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contacts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT, useremail TEXT)";     
    var selectAllStatement = "SELECT * FROM Contacts";     
    var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Contacts (username, useremail) VALUES (?, ?)";     
    var updateStatement = "UPDATE Contacts SET username = ?, useremail = ? WHERE id=?";     
    var deleteStatement = "DELETE FROM Contacts WHERE id=?";     
    var dropStatement = "DROP TABLE Contacts";     
     var db = openDatabase("AddressBook", "1.0", "Address Book", 200000);  // Open SQLite Database     
    var dataset;     
    var DataType;     
     function initDatabase()  // Function Call When Page is ready.     
    {     
        try {     
            if (!window.openDatabase)  // Check browser is supported SQLite or not.     
            {     
                alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');     
            }     
            else {     
                createTable();  // If supported then call Function for create table in SQLite     
            }     
        }     
        catch (e) {     
            if (e == 2) {     
                // Version number mismatch.      
                console.log("Invalid database version.");     
            } else {     
                console.log("Unknown error " + e + ".");     
            }     
            return;     
        }     
    }     
    function createTable()  // Function for Create Table in SQLite.     
    {     
        db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(createStatement, [], showRecords, onError); });     
    }     
    function insertRecord() // Get value from Input and insert record . Function Call when Save/Submit Button Click..     
    {     
            var usernametemp = $('input:text[id=username]').val();     
            var useremailtemp = $('input:text[id=useremail]').val();
            db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(insertStatement, [usernametemp, useremailtemp], loadAndReset, onError); });     
            //tx.executeSql(SQL Query Statement,[ Parameters ] , Sucess Result Handler Function, Error Result Handler Function );     
    }     
    function deleteRecord(id) // Get id of record . Function Call when Delete Button Click..

    {
             var iddelete = id.toString();     
        db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(deleteStatement, [id], showRecords, onError); alert("Delete Sucessfully"); });     
        resetForm();     
    }     
    function updateRecord() // Get id of record . Function Call when Delete Button Click..     
    {     
        var usernameupdate = $('input:text[id=username]').val().toString();     
        var useremailupdate = $('input:text[id=useremail]').val().toString();     
        var useridupdate = $("#id").val();     
        db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(updateStatement, [usernameupdate, useremailupdate, Number(useridupdate)], loadAndReset, onError); });     
    }     
    function dropTable() // Function Call when Drop Button Click.. Talbe will be dropped from database.     
    {     
        db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(dropStatement, [], showRecords, onError); });     
        resetForm();     
        initDatabase();     
    }     
    function loadRecord(i) // Function for display records which are retrived from database.     
    {     
        var item = dataset.item(i);     
        $("#username").val((item['username']).toString());     
        $("#useremail").val((item['useremail']).toString());     
        $("#id").val((item['id']).toString());     
    }     
    function resetForm() // Function for reset form input values.     
    {     
        $("#username").val("");     
        $("#useremail").val("");
        $("#id").val("");     
    }     
    function loadAndReset() //Function for Load and Reset...     
    {     
        resetForm();     
        showRecords()     
    }     
    function onError(tx, error) // Function for Hendeling Error...     
    {     
        alert(error.message);     
    }     
    function showRecords() // Function For Retrive data from Database Display records as list     
    {     
        $("#results").html('')     
        db.transaction(function (tx) {     
            tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {     
                dataset = result.rows;     
                for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {     
                    item = dataset.item(i);     
                    var linkeditdelete = '<li>' + item['username'] + ' , ' + item['useremail'] + '    ' + '<a href="#" onclick="loadRecord(' + i + ');">edit</a>' + '    ' +     
                                                '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRecord(' + item['id'] + ');">delete</a></li>';     
                    $("#results").append(linkeditdelete);     
                }     
            });     
        });     
    }     
    $(document).ready(function () // Call function when page is ready for load..     
    {
    ;     
        $("body").fadeIn(2000); // Fede In Effect when Page Load..     
        initDatabase();     
        $("#submitButton").click(insertRecord);  // Register Event Listener when button click.     
        $("#btnUpdate").click(updateRecord);     
        $("#btnReset").click(resetForm);     
        $("#btnDrop").click(dropTable);     
    });     
   </script>      
   </html>


<span style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: small;">
```

Please Give me any idea about my Problem 
Thank in Advanced

Comment: You cannot create a database using jQuery as it is a client side language. You will need a server-side layer such as ASP.Net or PHP which your JS will communicate with, and then perform tasks on your database.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

Comment: @GeraldSchneider did you even read that link you posted? I'm guessing not since you missed the gigantic `Beware. This specification is no longer in active maintenance and the Web Applications Working Group does not intend to maintain it further.`. And the fact that this was completely abandoned in 2010.

Comment: I did, but that's what he is using.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sqlite database, in the browser, you have the js code.
First, you have to call the createTable function, (but you have to fill the createStatement with a correct create stament.
Ex.: "CREATE TABLE users (id, name, whatever you need)"
Later you have to insert data into the created table. A valid insert stament will look like "INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,"jOHN", "fOO");

Comment: Thanks for Reply but i tried but call CreateTable Function but it's not call i placed alert but alert also not call please give me any idea about that